# How to migrate an existing web application from Heroku to AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, heroku-cli

I am using Heroku for my django web app, but I don't want to use it anymore, but now I am looking for a way to migrate the app from Heroku  to AWS elastic bean I would love to hear  that please explain and i am using django defualt sqlite3 db

Comment: If you're afraid you'll lose your data just back it up. Connect to it using DBeaver or some other client and back it up before starting the transfer.

Comment: @EneP I am also looking for the answer to how to migrate app from Heroku to aws if you know please write the answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are many way to migrate to AWS, it depends on which approach you would like to go for.

1. You have the expertises in managing server and don't mind maintaining it; Use EC2: https://medium.com/saarthi-ai/ec2apachedjango-838e3f6014ab
2. You just want to deploy it and don't want to deal with server/patching and so on using Elastic BeanStalk: https://www.andrlik.org/dispatches/migrate-django-heroku-elastic-beanstalk/
3. Cost is very important to you, you may use AWS lightsail: https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/
4. You application is containerized, you may use AWS ECS: https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-django-to-ecs-with-terraform/